# Can I have two planeswalkers with the same planeswalker type out on the field?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[image]

Can I have two versions of Huatli out at the same time even though they are the same planeswalker, just with different names?

Answer (score 33):

**Yes, you can have multiple Huatli planeswalkers on the battlefield at a time.**

This is a recent change when it comes to magic, but planeswalkers are now [Legendary](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Legendary) permanents so planeswalker type is no longer considered for determining if it gets to stay on the field.

> **306.4.**: Previously, planeswalkers were subject to a “planeswalker uniqueness rule” that stopped a player from controlling two planeswalkers of the same planeswalker type. This rule has been removed and planeswalker cards printed before this change have received errata in the Oracle card reference to have the legendary supertype. Like other legendary permanents, they are subject to the “legend rule” (see rule 704.5j).
>
> **704.5j**: If a player controls two or more legendary permanents with the same name, that player chooses one of them, and the rest are put into their owners’ graveyards. This is called the “legend rule.”

So as long as the two planeswalkers don't have the same card name, you can have them both on the battlefield simultaneously.

Comment: In addition you can have nonlegendary copies of a PW. Currently only Jace, Cunning Castaway has the ability to create tokens of itself, but maybe some other cards will allow you in the future to create new PW-token. Thinking of a Gideon made a creature with Helm of the Host... oooh... since the Gideon-soldier still is a PW... ooooh, this could be fun =D

Comment: @ErikLohmann Yup, you can also use [mtg:Mirror Gallery] to get around the restriction

Answer (score -9):

If those are the two cards you are meaning then no because of the  Legendary Planeswalker - Huatli

Comment: This is incorrect. The Legend rule only stops you from controlling 2 cards with the same name; the 2 cards in the OP each have a different name. The fact that they are both versions of Huatli doesn't matter (it used to matter with the Planeswalker uniqueness rule, but that rule no longer exists).

Comment: This answer was once true, but is outdated. The change is as of Ixialan, where the planeswalker rule (which cared about type) was removed and all planeswalkers were made legendary, and subject to the legend rule (which cares about name not type)